# How to remove or hide last level tree node in treeview C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, treeview

I have a page that display the tree level like below:

[image]

If user login as 'admin', he/she can view the full depth of the tree level.(like the image above). But if user login as'salesman', he/she can only view the ('TESTING SDN BHD', 'ABC'), ('SAMPLE SDN BHD', 'DEF'). Which means that salesman unable to view the 'TOWER A', 'TOWER B', 'TOWER C'.

I have tried to set the maxdatabinddepth = 2, but it also display all level of tree.

My ASPX Code:

```
<cc1:PSSTreeView ID="tvTreeProject" runat="server" ShowLines="True" TreeData="Tree"
            HiddenFieldTextBoxId="HFProject" NodeClickJSFunction="SetTreeDiv" ExpandAllOnRefresh="True"
            DisplayDivId="divProjectDisplay" AutoGenerateDataBindings="True" MaxDataBindDepth="2" 
            ExpandDepth="FullyExpand" ShowExpandCollapse="True">
        </cc1:PSSTreeView>
```

I am quite blur about how to hide the last level of treeview. Please help me! Thank you.

Comment: Fetch/change the data of desired depth for admin/salesman will be good solution, removing node after binding is another option, can use jQuery for this.

Answer (score 1):

You can handle your tree in `Page_Load` event of master or whatever page you using for the `treeView` to display.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  if (salesPerson)
  {
    TreeNodeCollection nodes = TreeView1.Nodes;
    foreach (TreeNode item in nodes)//TESTING SDN BHD
    {
     foreach (TreeNode item2 in item.ChildNodes)//ABC
     {
       for (int i = 0; i < item2.ChildNodes.Count; i++)
       {
         item2.ChildNodes[i].Text = "";//TOWERs to empty string, it's hiding the node
       }
       item2.Collapse();//It will Collapse the paretn node to hide space of child nodes
     }
   }
 }
```

Its not a recommended way of traversing the tree.
This is tested code to fulfil your requirement, if you need anything else, let me know.

Hope it helps!

Comment: I am populating the treeview control using a Web.sitemap. In this case, the Nodes collection has a count of 0 and so this method doesn't work for me. But thanks anyway.